# Jquery function to format textarea data

Tags: jquery

I have created a jquery function to format my text box data....such that I have a formatted output to my input box.

```
jQuery.fn.singleDotHyphen = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.val(function(){
            return $this.val()
                .replace(/\.{2,}/g, '.')
                .replace(/\'{2,}/g, "\'")
                .replace(/\,{2,}/g, ",")
                .replace(/\n{3,}/g, "\n\n")
                .replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ")                
                .replace(/-{2,}/g, '-');    
        });
    });
};
```

I have created it for newline that if more than 3 new lines are present than it convert it to 2 newline. But issue is if it find more than 3 nwe line than it convert it two space. How can I differentiate in both constraints that is of space and newline.

Answer (score 1):

`\s` matches any white-space character, including space, tab and **linefeed**.

Switch from `/\s{2,}/g` to `/ {2,}/g` if you want to match literal spaces only.